# Casting a HashMap

Tags: java, collections, casting, hashmap

i´m trying to make a casting of Hasmap

I have this hasmap:

```
 Map<String, Object> requestargs = new  Map<String, Object>();
```

Other side i have a method who bring me a hashmap of: `Map<String, Document>`

```
MultipartForm form = MgnlContext.getWebContext().getPostedForm();
```

The method is getDocuments();

I need to put the return of this method in my hashmap making something like this:

```
requestargs = form.getDocuments();
```

But i don´t know how to cast this Hasmap og (String,Document) to (String,Object)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you can use a wildcard

```
Map<String, ? extends Object> requestargs
```

You will need to copy the map into a new map:

```
requestargs = new HashMap<String, Object>(form.getDocuments());
```

The two types are not related directly. Were you able to make the assignment directly (or via casting) it would be possible to insert a value with non-`Document` type into the map, and that would be type-unsafe:

```
Map<String, Document> docs = form.getDocuments();
Map<String, Object> requestargs = docs;  // not actually allowed
requestargs.put("Foo", new Object());
for (Document doc : docs.values()) {
  // doc isn't necessarily a Document! ClassCastExceptions abound.
}
```

To prevent this problem happening, such an assignment is forbidden by the type system.

The wildcard works because it makes it impossible to call `put` on the map, since there is no way to know what types can be put into the map safely.

Comment: This not function :(
Map<String, Object> requestargs = docs;  // not actually allowed

Comment: What do you think "not actually allowed" means?

Comment: A shorthand for `Map<String, ? extends Object>` is just `Map<String, ?>`.